# How to separate searchable attributes to separate search boxes in Algolia?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algolia, search-box, instantsearch

If I have "title" and "category" as searchable attributes in the Algolia admin, is there any way that I can have one `<SearchBox />` searching only on "title" and another searching only on "category"?

At the moment, a `<SearchBox />` component from `react-instantsearch-dom` appears to search **ALL** searchable attributes. I would ideally like to separate the searches.

I could not find anything for this kind of setup in the documentation:
https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/search-box/react/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From Algolia [docs](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/widgets/configure/react/), you could use a `Configure` widget lets you provide raw search parameters to the Algolia API and pass in value for the `restrictSearchableAttributes` property. like so:

```
import { Configure } from 'react-instantsearch-dom';

<Configure
  restrictSearchableAttributes={["title"]}
/>
```

It doesn’t render anything on screen, it only applies the provided search parameters passed in once the component mounts

Comment: As far as I understand, this provides search parameters to the query...but how does this work with the same result set? I want 2 individual search boxes. One that searches on title and another that searches on category. If I set up 2 <Configure /> components, surely that wouldn't work.

Comment: Hi @MichaelGiovanniPumo, did you find any solution for your need? I have the same problem.